# Schedule a 6-day timetable for 5 days in python

Tags: python, schedule

I'm creating an automation in Python, that will automatically navigate to my school's website, and join the online class, etc using selenium. I've completely finished that part, and it all works perfectly. Now, I'm trying to figure out how to schedule these actions.

I was thinking of using [schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule)? It seems good for straightforward jobs, but I don't know if it would be any good for something like this.

I have 10 classes in total. I have 6 classes in a day. My school week goes from Monday and Friday. In my timetable, there are a total of *6 days*, meaning that every week, one day in the timetable gets rotated out, and I don't have it that week, and another rotates in.

So, to further explain what I mean by that, in the first week, I would have Days 1-5 Monday to Friday, but I would not have Day 6. I *would* have Day 6 the following Monday.

I've defined the days as follows:

```py
import configparser
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()


<defining what each class does here with selenium, etc.>


# Defining what classes I have in each day

def Day1():
    class()
    class()
    class()
    class()
    class()
    class()

def Day2():
    class()
    class()
    class()
    class()
    class()
    class()

def Day3():
    class()
    class()
    class()
    class()
    class()
    class()

def Day4():
    class()
    class()
    class()
    class()
    class()
    class()

def Day5():
    class()
    class()
    class()
    class()
    class()
    class()

def Day6():
    class()
    class()
    class()
    class()
    class()
    class()
```

Each `class` just being a **different** class I have each day. Some are the same, some are different, but it doesn't really matter for this question. (I've just called them all `class` for this question cos it's easier)

How do I go about scheduling these days (Day1 - Day6) so that they run on Monday to Friday with one day rotating out and then back in the next week (as I described above)?

The Python [`schedule`](https://github.com/dbader/schedule) module seems like it would be able to do it, but I don't even know where to start with that when I have something like this.

I feel like it would be a pretty simple solution, but I can't seem to work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate which day of the school term it is, and mod that by 6.  A good starting point would be this bit of code, to get the current day within the current year:

```
from datetime import datetime
day_of_year = datetime.now().timetuple().tm_yday
```

You'll also want to figure out which day of the year was the first day of school.  Call that `first_day_of_school`.  Then, assuming school started on a Monday:

```
day_of_school = day_of_year - first_day_of_school
week_of_school = day_of_school // 7
day_of_week = day_of_school % 7 # 0 means Monday, European style
day_of_term = week_of_school * 5 + day_of_week
class_index = day_of_term % 6
```

Now `class_index` is the number in [0, 5] telling you which set of classes to attend on this day.

You may need to adjust this for holidays, e.g. if a Friday holiday means the Friday classes are not skipped but shifted to Monday.  For that you need proper business day arithmetic, which can be done easily and efficiently using NumPy or other libraries, or you can just hard-code a list of holidays and do it brute-force, since a school term is only a few months long.

Comment: Thanks for that! And by first day of school, you mean the *very* first day, not the first day of term?

Comment: I mean the first day when the schedule starts, which to my mind means the first day of the term.  That's your baseline, you need to know how far into the school term/schedule you are.

Comment: So for `first_day_of school`, I have `first_day_of_school = datetime(2020, 10, 6).timetuple().tm_yday`. Am I on the right track? Just want to be 100%.

Comment: If i set first day of school to the 21st, it says today (26th) is 5, shouldn't it be skipping weekends?

Comment: The `// 7` and `* 5` parts are how weekends are skipped.

Comment: And if school was to start on another day (e.g. Tuesday), I'd have to change them to something else? Sorry I'm still just trying to wrap my head around all this.

Comment: Just write down some examples on paper, I'm sure you can work it out once you try some.